# MSK Not Deleting Old Messages

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

I have three MSK clusters; dev, nonprod & prod. They all have the following cluster configuration - there is no topic level configuration.

```
auto.create.topics.enable=false
default.replication.factor=3
min.insync.replicas=2
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=5
num.partitions=1
num.replica.fetchers=2
log.retention.hours=100
replica.lag.time.max.ms=30000
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
unclean.leader.election.enable=true
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=18000
```

Dev and Nonprod are clearing down messages older than 100 hours as defined in the `log.retention.hours=100` setting.

We have a lot more traffic coming through our production cluster and old messages are not being removed. **We have hundreds of thousands of messages older than 400 hours still on the cluster.** I have thought about adding further config settings such as

```
segment.bytes
segment.ms
```

To roll the segments quicker as maybe a segment hasn't rolled yet and can't be marked for deletion - however this same config is working nicely in the other clusters albeit not receiving as much traffic.

Comment: Is there any value set to log.cleanup.policy? Also, is the version of Kafka same across all the environments?

Comment: Hi, all clusters are running 2.2.1 and I have not explicitly set log.cleanup.policy as that defaults to delete reading from the kafka config guide (seems to be working in dev & nonprod).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this turned out to be an issue with a Producer sending messages to Kafka in a US date format rather than UK. Therefore, it created messages that would appear to be timestamped in the future - hence not be older than 100 hours and eligible for deletion.

To remove the existing message we set `log.retention.bytes` which prunes messages irrespective of the `log.retention.hours` setting. This caused the kafka topic to be pruned and delete the erroneous message - we then unset `log.retention.bytes`.

Next we set the `log.message.timestamp.type=LogAppendTime` to ensure that messages are stamped with a queue time as apposed to the document time. This will prevent bad dates from producers causing this issue again in the future.

Comment: Using CreateTime appears to allow interference with `log.roll.ms` with compacted topics as well